# typo3 TypoScript creating a menu for subpages from any page of any level

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I try to get the children to the actual page.

This is my best try:

```
      10 {
          dataProcessing {
              100 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\MenuProcessor
              100 {
                levels = 1
                entryLevel = page:level
                includeSpacer = 1
                includeNotInMenu = 0
                as = children
                expandAll = 0
              }
          }

      }
```

I tried to get the menu level of the current page, but I couldn't find something in the documentation that is helping.
Do you have an idea?

My goal is to create a menu for all subpages at the next level.

Thank you for your time :-)

Adjusted solution:

```
      10 {
          dataProcessing {
          100 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\MenuProcessor
          100 {
              as = children
              special = directory
              special.value.field = pages
              dataProcessing {
                  10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
                  10 {
                      references.fieldName = media
                  }
              }
          }
```

props @Thomas Löffler
Danke ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a content element in TYPO3 named "menu of subpages" which is integrated in TypoScript as well.

What I got from the core (https://github.com/TYPO3/typo3/blob/main/typo3/sysext/fluid_styled_content/Configuration/TypoScript/ContentElement/MenuSubpages.typoscript):

```
tt_content.menu_subpages =< lib.contentElement
tt_content.menu_subpages {
    templateName = MenuSubpages
    dataProcessing {
        10 = menu
        10 {
            special = directory
            special.value.field = pages
            dataProcessing {
                10 = files
                10 {
                    references.fieldName = media
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't want to display any images you can remove the files part.

Beware that the example is taken from latest version. There you can replace the dataprocessor class names.